# Remove same values in a string

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to remove duplicated values in a string?

e.g: `aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, bbb, ccc, eee, fff, ggg`

the expected output be like: `aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff, ggg`

I have no idea how should I achieve on this.

Comment: @SandeepNayak string

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: @PeterSmith to be fair i haven't tried much yet, because i'm kind of new to JS and like i said above, i have no idea how to go on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EcmaScript5* solution using `String.prototype.match()` and `Array.prototype.filter()` functions:

```js
var str = 'aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, bbb, ccc, eee, fff, ggg',
    unique_items = str.match(/\b\w+\b/g).filter(function (el, idx, a) {
        return idx === a.lastIndexOf(el);
    });

// unique_items.sort();  // to get a sorted list of words(alphabetically)
console.log(unique_items);

// back to string
console.log(unique_items.join(', '));
```

It will also cover such *sophisticated* input strings as `'aaa, bbb,, ccc, ddd, bbb, ccc? eee,, fff, ggg,,'`

Comment: is it just because it's the console.log or will the [] and "" appear in the output?

Comment: @Damon, pay attention, the answer gives the expected output, no empty strings

Answer (score 1):

**Using Reduce Function with out disturb the existing order**

```
var names = ["No","Speaking","Guy","No","Test","Solutions","No"];

var uniq = names.reduce(function(a,b){
    if (a.indexOf(b) < 0 ) a.push(b);
    return a;
  },[]);

console.log(uniq, names) // [ 'No', 'Speaking', 'Guy', 'Test', 'Solutions' ]

// one liner
return names.reduce(function(a,b){if(a.indexOf(b)<0)a.push(b);return a;},[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string at the commas and then put the result array in a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). The set object is like an array, but it only stores 1 of each value.

```
var set = new Set(yourString.split(","));
var distinctValues = Array.from(set).join();
```